# How to right-justify the last two (or more) items in a flexbox layout?

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to create a CSS flexbox layout in which the first several items are left-justified and then several additional items are right-justified. The right-aligned items should always remain right-justified regardless of wrapping.

When there is only a single final right-justified item, this can be achieved with `style='margin-left: auto;'` on the final item. But I don't see how to do this with **two or more** right-justified items. (Similarly, if only the first item is left-justified, then `style='margin-right: auto;'` on that item and `justify-content: flex-end;` on the container would do the job.)

In the example below, the first 3 items should be left-justified, and the last 2 items should be right-justified, regardless of wrapping. The last 2 items should wrap independently of one another. Also, while I've made all child items the same width in this example, in my real use case, they can each be different widths.

- If I put `style='margin-left: auto;'` on the 4th item, then it works if **both** item 4 and item 5 wrap, but it fails if only item 5 wraps.
- If I put `style='margin-left: auto;'` on both the 4th and 5th items, I get unwanted margin whitespace between items 4 and 5 when they are on the same line.

Is this possible? I'm scratching my head...

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  column-gap: 1em;
  row-gap: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.flexcontainer div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div>item 1 - left</div>
  <div>item 2 - left</div>
  <div>item 3 - left</div>
  <div style="margin-left: auto;">item 4 - right</div>
  <div>item 5 - right</div>
</div>

<div class="flexcontainer" style="border: 1px solid green;">
  <div>item 1 - left</div>
  <div>item 2 - left</div>
  <div>item 3 - left</div>
  <div style="margin-left: auto;">item 4 - right</div>
  <div style="margin-left: auto;">item 5 - right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the old float and inline-block can do it:

```css
.flexcontainer {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: right; /* align all to the right */
  padding:0.5em;
}
.flexcontainer div {
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin:.5em;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexcontainer div:nth-child(-n + 3) {
  float:left; /* keep the first 3 to the left*/
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <div>item 1 - left</div>
  <div>item 2 - left</div>
  <div>item 3 - left</div>
  <div>item 4 - right</div>
  <div>item 5 - right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow... so throw away flexbox altogether?! This might work for my use case... I have to think through the impact on my layout. I'm also still curious to see if someone responds with a flexbox solution.

Comment: Checking back here after a few months... No one has suggested a way to do this via flexbox itself. Perhaps the answer is "can't be done!"